# User/Passport not persisting on page navigation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, passport.js, session-cookies

The user cookie data is not being persisted across page navigations and on reloads it completely loses the session.

Backend Files

Server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const articleRouter = require('./routes/articles')
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
const privacyRouter = require('./routes/privacy')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const {connectDB, sessionStore} = require('./config/db')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport)

const app = express()

//Frontend talking to Backend
app.use(cors({
  origin:'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE',
  credentials: true
}));

//Middleware Handling
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())

// Logging
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

//Connects to database
connectDB()

// Sessions
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: 'lax',  //change to none for production
    secure: false //set to true for production
  }
}))

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// Middleware to log session information
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Session: ${JSON.stringify(req.session)}`);
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
app.use('/articles', articleRouter)
app.use('/privacy', privacyRouter)

//Port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}...`))
```

db.js file (database configuration)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })


const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('MongoDB connected!')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`)
            });
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
};


const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    autoRemove: 'native',
    collectionName: 'sessions'
})

module.exports = {connectDB, sessionStore}
```

passport.js file (passport configuration)

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const User = require('../models/user')

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
        scope: ['profile']
    }, async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
            const newUser = {
                googleId: profile.id,
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                lastName: profile.name.familyName,
                image: profile.photos[0].value
            };

            try {
                const user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id});

                if(user) {
                    return cb(null, user);
                } else {
                    user = await User.create(newUser);
                    return cb(null, user);
                }

            } catch (err) {
                console.error("Error signing in/up",err);
                return cb(err, null);
            }

        }
    ))

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        console.log('SerializedUser:', user);
        return done(null, user.id)
    })

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id).then((user) => {
            console.log(`deserializeUser called with id: ${id}`)
            console.log(`Deserialize user: ${user}`)
            done(null, user)
        })
    })
}
```

Frontend files

axios.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'
});
```

User Component:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import {UserContext} from '../Context/UserContext'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const User = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
  const {userArticles, setUserArticles} = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () =>{
      console.log('getUser function ran');
      const res = await axios.get('/articles/user', { withCredentials: true });
      console.log('Axios user res:', res)
      if(res.status === 200){
        setUser({...res.data.user, loggedIn: true});
        setUserArticles(res.data.article)
      }
    }  
    console.log('User useEffect Hook ran');
    getUser();
  }, [setUser, setUserArticles])

  return (
    <section className="blog-container">
      {userArticles.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Welcome {user.firstName}!!! You have no blogs</div>
      ) : (
        userArticles.map(article => {
          return (
            <div key={article._id} className="blog-card">
              <Link className="card-link" to={`/articles/${article.slug}`}>
                Read More
              </Link>
              <div className="blog-auth">
                <Link to={`./blog/${article.user.id}`}>
                  <img
                    className="user-image"
                    src={article.user.image}
                    alt="user's google profile pic"
                  />
                </Link>
                <p className="blog-subtitle">
                  {new Date(article.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="blog-details">
                <h2 className="blog-title">{article.title}</h2>
                <div className="blog-content">{article.description}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      )}
    </section>
  )
}
```

export default User

I have double-checked to ensure the Axios in the front end have withCredentials set to true and that cors, in the back end, also have credentials set to true.